# Update Oracle JDK

Tags: debian, java, jdk

I know, there are several ways of installing ORACLE jdk7 on Debian. One way is to use the ppa from the web8updteam but i've read that installing software from ppa is not recommended on Debian. (is this true, btw??)

So I decided to follow this guide to install oracle jdk. Here it's recommended to use java-package to generate a .deb package of the jdk binaries and then install it via dpkg:

```
$ make-jpkg jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ su

$ dpkg -i oracle-j2sdk1.7_1.7.0+update45_amd64.deb
```

The problem with this approach is, that I will loose continuous updates of the jdk.

So, my question is, how do I actually update to a newer jdk? Simply download the newer jdk, remove the current installed jdk with dpkg -r and repeat the instructions above again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to update to a newer JDK you need to repeat the process manually.

The [webupd8team ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html) is a far more convenient way to get the Oracle JDK with automatic updates.

You are right, as stated in [Debian Basic Precautions](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_precautions):

> Do not mix standard Debian with other non-Debian archives such as Ubuntu in "/etc/apt/sources.list".

But in this case (from www.webupd8.org):

> the WebUpd8 Java 7 PPA works on Debian too since the package is just an installer and all you have to do is manually add the PPA repository to the Software Sources.

Anyway, speaking of recommendations, the Debian Wiki at wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage says about the Java package builder:

> Debian recommends the use of OpenJDK which is packaged and available in all Debian releases.